# Node.js: Synchronous HTTP endpoint

Tags: node.js, express

We have a small application that supports POSTing a XML message to an endpoint that validates XML's and if they are correct put them on an event bus. The developer who made this application built it in Node.JS and this is where we are getting into trouble. Some messages are posted with only a few milliseconds apart from each other.

It seems that the order isn't always correct when it is placed on the event bus. I was wondering if there is a solution to guarantee an order?

The application is using express.js as a http server.

```
app.post("/", async (request, response) => {
        // do some stuff
    });
```

Comment: Maybe a intermediate storage (in-memory), you store some data, and put in event bus sorted with time. Not sure, if that would work for you.

Comment: Is there more code you could provide?